# Counting the number of option tags in a select tag in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I count the number of `<option>`s in a `<select>` DOM element using jQuery?

```
<select data-attr="dropdown" id="input1">
  <option value="Male" id="Male">Male</option>
  <option value="Female" id="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

I want to find the number of `<option>` tags in the `<select>` DOM element, since with that I want to open the settings panel with that number of input fields with the corresponding option value from the drop-down box in it and to change it again in the preview panel.

The above drop-down box is in my preview panel which is generated by jQuery.

Answer (score 295):

```
$('#input1 option').length;
```

This will produce `2`.

Answer (score 61):

The W3C solution:

```
var len = document.getElementById("input1").length;
```

Comment: A variation to this method with modern javascript will be  

`var len = document.querySelector("#input1").length;`

Answer (score 32):

You can use either **[length](http://api.jquery.com/length/)** property and `length` is better on performance than `size`.

```
$('#input1 option').length;
```

OR you can use **[size](http://api.jquery.com/size/)** function like (removed in jQuery v3)

```
$('#input1 option').size();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   console.log($('#input1 option').size());
   console.log($('#input1 option').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-attr="dropdown" id="input1">
   <option value="Male" id="Male">Male</option>
   <option value="Female" id="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This doesn't provide anything the answers from 2009 didn't also provide.

Answer (score 19):

Your question is a little confusing, but assuming you want to display the number of options in a panel:

```
<div id="preview"></div>
```

and

```
$(function() {
  $("#preview").text($("#input1 option").length + " items");
});
```

Not sure I understand the rest of your question.

Answer (score 15):

In a multi-select option box, you can use `$('#input1 :selected').length;` to get the number of selected options. This can be useful to disable buttons if a certain minimum number of options aren't met.

```
function refreshButtons () {
    if ($('#input :selected').length == 0)
    {
        $('#submit').attr ('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#submit').removeAttr ('disabled');
    }
}
```

Comment: I found this to work after removing the braces
`$('#input1 :selected').length;`

supporting documentation https://api.jquery.com/length/

Answer (score 7):

The best form is this

```
$('#example option').length
```

Comment: This code-only (low-value) solution was provided 4 years earlier by Sadikhasan.  The use of `length` was posted by Karim79 9 years earlier.  This answer can safely be purged from the page as it is completely redundant.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, i had a few problems because i was inside a

```
$('.my-dropdown').live('click', function(){  
});
```

I had multiples inside my page that's why i used a class.

My drop down was filled automatically by a ajax request when i clicked it, so i only had the element $(this)

so...

I had to do:

```
$('.my-dropdown').live('click', function(){
  total_tems = $(this).find('option').length;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is giving the count of all the *available* options exactly as the question asked.  Its useful if you already have the node in a variable

Answer (score -1):

Another approach that can be useful.

```
$('#select-id').find('option').length
```

Comment: The question isn’t asking for the count of _only selected_ `<option>`s.