# How do I check how many options there are in a dropdown menu?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

How do I check, using jQuery, how many options are there in a drop down menu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

```
var length = $('#mySelectList').children('option').length;
```

or

```
var length = $('#mySelectList > option').length;
```

This assumes your `<select>` list has an ID of `mySelectList`.

- http://api.jquery.com/length/
- http://api.jquery.com/children/
- http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: `.children('option').length;` was the only way I could get the actual option count / select.length after I populated my select list dynamically via ajax in the .done({}); using .append(). Way to go!

Comment: for the length of selected options is this correct "$('.search-select option:selected').length"

Comment: Regarding @yardpenalty.com 's response, the reason is because the .children() version parses the current DOM, while the second one with $('#mySelectList > option') parses the DOM that existed when the page was loaded.

Answer (score 11):

```
$("#mydropdown option").length
```

Or if you already got a reference to it,

```
$(myDropdown).find("option").length
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the [length property](http://api.jquery.com/length/) or [the size method](http://api.jquery.com/size/) to find out how many items are in a jQuery collection. Use the [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) to select all `<option>`'s within a `<select>`.

HTML:

```
<select id="myDropDown">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
.
.
.
</select>
```

JQuery:

```
var numberOfOptions = $('select#myDropDown option').length
```

And a quick note, often you will need to do something in jquery for a very specific thing, but you first need to see if the very specific thing exists.  The length property is the perfect tool.
example:

```
   if($('#myDropDown option').length > 0{
      //do your stuff..
    }
```

This 'translates' to "If item with ID=myDropDown has any descendent 'option' s, go do what you need to do.

Answer (score 5):

Get the number of options in a particular select element

```
$("#elementid option").length
```

Comment: There is no advantage to using ".size" over ".length" which is slightly faster.

Answer (score 5):

[Click here to see a previous post about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152738/counting-the-number-of-options-tag-in-the-select-dom-element-in-jquery)

Basically just target the ID of the select and do this:

```
var numberOfOptions = $('#selectId option').length;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#idofdropdown option').length;
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
alert($('#select_id option').length);
```

Comment: This will work, but not if the DOM changes after load. See accepted answer above for details.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#dropdown_id').find('option').length
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('select option').length;
```

or

```
$("select option").size()
```

Comment: `.size()` is useful if you want to chain

Comment: .size() returns and integer and, therefore, is not chain-able.  You can only chain methods that return jQuery objects.

Answer (score 1):

With pure javascript you can just call the length on the id of the select box. 
It will be more faster. 
Typically with everything native javascript is performing better and better with modern browsers

This can be achieved in javascript by

```
     var dropdownFilterSite = document.querySelector( '#dropDownId' );  //Similar to jQuery

var length = dropdownFilterSite.length.
```

Good website for some learning

www.youmightnotneedjquery.com

A good video to watch by Todd Motto

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLISnANteJY