# How to count number of option tags using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, count, html-select

I have a question as to how can I calculate number of options tag when I have multiple select box with same class and id?

Let's say I have three select boxes. And I want the size of select box, so that I can dynamically add new select box with the same options:

```
<select id="selectid" class="selectclass">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>

<select id="selectid" class="selectclass">
    <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
</select>

<select id="selectid" class="selectclass">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Having multiple elements sharing the same `ID` is invalid HTML...

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152738/counting-the-number-of-options-tag-in-the-select-dom-element-in-jquery

Answer (score 63, accepted):

with jquery:

for a given `select` with an `id`:

```
$('select#selectid option').length
```

for all `selects` with a given class:

```
$('select.selectclass option').length
```

for all `selects` in the page:

```
$('select option').length
```

but you should give different Ids to each element in a html page

Comment: Nope..its giving me the multiple of option tags.. for the above example its returning 6. But I need 2 as my answer.

Comment: because you're giving the same id to all selects

Comment: @mad_programmer: Stop using IDs incorrectly and it won't be an issue.

Comment: don't remove the ids if you are using the fisrt option (with ids). Just give diffrent ids (selectid1, selectid2, selectid3) and replace `#selectid` with the id of your choice. For example, if you want options count for select with an `id='select1'` -> use `$('select#select1 option').length`

Answer (score 1):

Tag IDs are supposed to be unique to a document.  Do you plan to have all of these in the document tree at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I found that I got more consistent results using the JQuery `children()` method, i.e.,

```
$('.productDetail_variant select').each(function() {
      var currSelectValue = $(this).children();
      alert(currSelectValue.length);
});
```

Comment: Just in case someone else finds this and thinks 'oh, this is a nice solution' it isn't. A select element remember can also have optgroups which would make the length wrong.

Comment: This works for me, not using optgroups. By the way specifying 'option' as children fixes the optgroups problem. In Chrome when I try size or length I always get 1 no matter what. Nice work! Here is the 1 liner: $('#select_id').children('option').length