# how can I calculate number of options tag when I get the select box with $this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question as to how can I calculate number of options tag when I get the select box with $this.

Like that:

```
 $("select[name=rabetas]").click(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
```

And...?

how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Select the `<option>` elements](http://api.jquery.com/children/), and then [get the `length`](http://api.jquery.com/length).

```
var numOptions = $this.children().length;
```

---

Learn to dig through the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/). They will answer 99% of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

[Counting the number of options tag in the Select Dom element in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152738/counting-the-number-of-options-tag-in-the-select-dom-element-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I believe you can use

```
$("select[name="rabetas"] option").size();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through a collection of select list items, inspecting the DOM will show that each item has an object array with one item so you can use the following code...

```
$('.myddlclass').each(function (index) {
    var options = $(this)[0].options.length;
});
```