# Jquery selector on child count

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Counting selection options is [easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152738/counting-the-number-of-options-tag-in-the-select-dom-element-in-jquery)

```
$('.myselect option').length;
```

But is there a shorthand selector that filter on the size? eg to do something like this?

```
$('.myselect').childCountBetween('option', 2, 4).hide();
```

ie running a jquery method (hide in this instance) on all `.myselect`s with between 2 and 4 options.

edit: to clarify - I'm wanting as selector that filters on the "parent" elements based on the child counts. Ie not wanting to hide options 2-4, but to hide select fields with between 2 and 4 items. A similar tasks would be add a class to ULs with 2-4 LIs etc. Sorry if original question was ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure this will be the solution you're looking for, but should work for what you described...

```
$.fn.childCountBetween = function (child, min, max) {
  return $(this).filter(function (id, el) {
     var children = $(el).find(child).length;
     return children > min && children < max;
  });
};

$('.myselect').childCountBetween('option', 2, 4).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) like,

```
$('.myselect option').slice( 2, 4 ).hide();
```

**Note**: **IE** doesn't allow you to manipulate `option elements directly`. For this, you have to `remove all` of the `option elements` from the select and `repopulate` them.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use jQuerys eq() function to find a specific index.

http://api.jquery.com/eq/